# How can I identify which problems are preventing log out?

Tags: windows-10, logout

I and a number of other users are having an issue with Windows 10 that may be related to an app that is locked on.  We can't tell which.  Except that it persists into log out and causes the usual warning about a program that is still open.  The icon that appears is the generic one used when there is no other available.

I need to identify which app it is (or if there are multiple ones).  This is not my area of expertise.  Are there any reports that identify slow/resistant apps at shutdown?  Any suggestions?

Comment: you can wait until its the only application listed, and then hit cancel. then immediately use a task manager to examine the processes running under that user. one of them will be the culprit. it should stand out, since its likely non-microsoft. In MS Task Manager, you can see user processes under the Users tab, by expanding the user in question.